# To use "import com.c*.e*.common.util.BatchLogWriter;", what jar files do I need to download in advance?

Tags: java, logging, import

I am trying to run some Java source code created by someone who has quit the job.
What jar files do I need to download in order to use:

```
import com.[myCompany].[myProject].common.util.BatchLogWriter;
```

Comment: Since that isn't legal syntax, the jar files are irrelevant.

Comment: I think I should download some jar files to enable such an import statement, am I wrong? I solved a similar issue by download the corresponding jar files. Do you mean those jar files are not available on the internet and they should be prepared by the developer himself?

Comment: Are the stars really part of the import statement, or you use it use it as a mask? Because asterisks is an illegal character in package names.

Comment: Sorry that I used stars to replace some characters (for confidential purpose)

Comment: It seems that I should find these jar files from somewhere inside the company.

Comment: You need the jar file containing the class you are trying to import. Since it seems to be a class created by someone in the company, then yes, that is where you should get it.

Comment: We assume that your company has not made public and published it to a public repository (Example http://mvnrepository.com/). So only your company can help.

Comment: Why do you expect people outside of your company to know about internals of your company?